# EF Core: Return all items that have item with property==x in their collection

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

thanks for advance for any help. I'm starting to learn EF Core, suppose I have these 2 classes:

```
 public class Post

{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}



public class Tag

{

    public Guid TagId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Guid PostId { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }

}
```

How do I form a query that returns all the posts that have a tag with the name "X"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word of caution, when doing string compares you can run into some issues with case sensitivity. I usually just lowercase everything when comparing if I don't need to have case sensitivity on in cases like pass codes or something like that.

```
var posts = await context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName.ToLower() == "tag name"))
    .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Yep, searched for an "exists" equivalent and this is just what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @ВладиславТрубников if this answers your question, kindly please accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sql server default collation is in my experience typically case insensitive. The ToLower is likely superfluous

Comment: True, by default it is. It still has bit me because a client used a case sensitive collation. Just pointing it is a potential issue. I agree this will work without the .ToLower() a majority of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var postsWithTagX = await context.Post
.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == "The Tag Id you want"))
.ToListAsync()
```

Edit:

You can get it from include.

```
var tag = await context.Tag
.Include(x => x.Post)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TagId == "The Tag Id you want");

var posts = tag.Posts.Tolist()
```